# Querying nested objects

Tags: search, elasticsearch, nested

Just to let things clear, first day working with Elastic... Moving to the problem.

I started to create my index with

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/users" -d'
{
   "mappings": {
      "user": {
         "properties": {
            "education": {
               "type": "nested"
            },
            "job": {
               "type": "nested"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

and then

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/users/user/" -d'
   {
      "name": "User A",
      "education": [
         {
            "school": "School A1",
            "course": "Course A1"
         },
         {
            "school": "School A2",
            "course": "Course A2"
         }
      ]
   }'
```

The problem that I'm facing now is the query part. I'm trying to get results with:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/users/user/_search?pretty" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "education",
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "education.school": "School A1"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

But nothing is getting returned.

Comment: You don't have a school in `education` field with value `School A`

Comment: Fixed, but still no results

Comment: Show the mapping school inside education object. Is it `analysed String`

Comment: {
  "users" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "user" : {
        "properties" : {
          "education" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "course" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "school" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "job" : {
            "type" : "nested"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: By default `standard analyser` will be applied on all Strings. Have provided an answer. Please see if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the mappings provided by you, `school` field is `analyzed`.
Analyzed means the text `School A` will split over space and will be tokenized as `School` and `A`.
you are searching using `term query` which looks for exact term. Study [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) about `term query`.

You can use `Query_string` with `default_operator`  as `AND`

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/users/user/_search?pretty" -d'
{
  "query": {
  "filtered": {
     "query": {
        "match_all": {}
     },
     "filter": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "education",
           "filter": {
              "bool": {
                 "must": [
                    {
                       "query": {
                          "query_string": {
                             "default_field": "education.school",
                             "query": "School A1",
                             "default_operator": "AND"
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
             }
        }
     }
     }
    }
 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving my 2 cents here. I would avoid using `filtered` query as it is being deprecated [Check this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#_literal_filtered_literal_query_and_literal_query_literal_filter_deprecated) in latest release of ES.

I'll just rewrite the above query without using `filtered query`

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/users/user/_search?pretty" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "education",
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "query_string": {
                        "default_field": "education.school",
                        "query": "School A1",
                        "default_operator": "AND"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

I followed [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) doc to write above query.